# How do you use ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet recognize_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, routes, actiondispatch

How do you use ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet recognize_path?

I want to get the current path for the view.

I tried `<div id="<%= ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::recognize_path %>">` but got "undefined method `recognize_path' for ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:Class".

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!   My question was 'How do you do the equivalent of Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/your/path"' in Rails 2.3?   It looks like that was the exact inverse of your question.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path of the Request:

```
request.path
```

Path of the file:

```
__FILE__
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/your/path"
```

It works in rails 3.1.0.rc4

Comment: This helped me a million. Thank you. (Still works in 3.1.0.rc6, too.)