# Detect links to site’s videos and show title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem.

I have a Video and Comment model.
If the user inserted the link to video into the comment, it is link to replace with the title from video.

How should I write a method?

```
def to_show_title_instead_of_the_link
  body.gsub!(%r{(videos)\/([0-9])}) {|link| link_to link)}
end
```

We input:

```
http://localhost:3000/videos/1
```

We receive:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/videos/1"> test video</a>
```

Comment: What you need is the regular expression to match "test video"?

Comment: @cortex no. instead of the link there shall be a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did refactoring code and used a gem [rinku](https://github.com/vmg/rinku)

```
def links_in_body(text)
  auto_link(text) do |url|
    video_id = url.match(/\Ahttps?:\/\/#{request.host_with_port}\/videos\/(\d+)\z/)
    if video_id.present?
      Video.find(video_id[1]).title
    else
      truncate(url, length: AppConfig.truncate.length)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to take a given URL on your site, and find the associated parameters for that route. This will let you get the `id` for the video in a clean, DRY way (without using a regex that might break later if your route changes). This will then let you look up the model instance and fetch its `title` field. The Rails method for this task is `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path`, which returns a hash with the action, controller, and path parameters.

In your view:

```
# app\views\comments\show.html.erb
# ...
<div class='comment-text'>
  replace_video_url_with_anchor_tag_and_title(comment.text)
</div>
# ...
```

And here is the helper method:

```
# app\helpers\comments_helper.rb
def replace_video_url_with_anchor_tag_and_title(comment_text)
  # assuming links will end with a period, comma, exclamation point, or white space
  # this will match all links on your site
  # the part in parentheses are relative paths on your site
  # \w matches alphanumeric characters and underscores. we also need forward slashes
  regex = %r{http://your-cool-site.com(/[\w/]+)[\.,!\s]?}
  comment_text.gsub(regex) do |matched|
    # $1 gives us the portion of the regex captured by the parentheses
    params = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path $1

    # if the link we found was a video link, replaced matched string with
    # an anchor tag to the video, with the video title as the link text
    if params[:controller] == 'video' && params[:action] == 'show' 
       video = Video.find params[:id]
       link_to video.title, video_path(video)

    # otherwise just return the string without any modifications
    else
       matched
    end
  end
end
```

I didn't know how to do this off the top of my head, but this is how I figured it out:

1) Google `rails reverse route`, and the first result was this stackoverflow question: [Reverse rails routing: find the the action name from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481731/reverse-rails-routing-find-the-the-action-name-from-the-url). The answer mentions `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path`. I fired up `rails console` and tried this out, however it is deprecated, and didn't actually work.

2) I then google `rails recognize_path`. The first search result was the docs, which were not very helpful. The third search result was [How do you use ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet recognize_path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459403/how-do-you-use-actiondispatchroutingrouteset-recognize-path), whose second solution actually worked.

3) Of course, I then had to go refresh my understanding of Ruby regex syntax and `gsub!`, and test out the regex I wrote above =)

Comment: No problem! I was actually just thinking about this a little more, and it isn't the cleanest way to just run this method on the entire `body` text. We should use it as a helper method for comment views, and run the regex just for the text of the comment. I updated my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I understand, thanks again. I will process your method and I will write his version.